# Retrieve LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1..5 based on LINK_ID

Tags: here-api

Assume I have a `LINK_ID` which I got using the `LINK_FC5` layer with `search/proximity` resource described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/resource-search-proximity.html).

Note that the `search/proximity` resource doesn't allow non-geometric layers such as `LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC5` to be specified.

> Errorcode: 400, message: Provided layer does not contain geometries.

The documentation suggests using `tile` resource for getting the non-geometric layers, but that seems quite inefficient. Within one tile there are many `LINK_ID`s. Hard for me to believe there is no better way to do this. Hence the question:

*What is a efficient way to retrieve all attributes from the `LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC5` layer using the `LINK_ID`?*

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share request that you are using ?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Sure: `https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/search/proximity.json?proximity=X,Y,R&key_attributes=LINK_ID&layer_ids=LINK_FC5` which results in a JSON from which I get: `"geometries" -> 1 -> "attributes" -> "LINK_ID"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to club to APIs to get the desired attributes for link IDs. So a tile comprises of multiple layers, Each layer contains multiple link IDs. this requires to make association between these resources. You can also refer to example : https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_get_any_link_info

First API is : 
https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/index.json?layer=ROAD_GEOM_FCn&attributes=LINK_ID&values=548294575,833539855,550088940,930893121&apiKey=xxx

The response will be like : 
"Layers": [
        {
            "layer": "ROAD_GEOM_FC5",
            "level": 13,
            "tileXYs": [
                {
                    "x": 8580,
                    "y": 6376
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "layer": "ROAD_GEOM_FC1",
            "level": 9,
            "tileXYs": [
                {
                    "x": 534,
                    "y": 397
                },
                {
                    "x": 536,
                    "y": 398
                }
            ]
        }

From here you will get level, tile x,y and layer, 
2nd API will be : 
https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tiles.json?apiKey=xx&tilexy=536,398&levels=13&layers=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC5